# Go to URL based on dynamic dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css, input

I am currently trying to allow my visitors to select 2 options from dynamic select dropdown boxes. Depending on the second selection, when they click a "Go" button they should be redirected to a url I choose. Each secondary selection will have different URL which it would visit.

This is where I am at the moment - https://jsfiddle.net/slinger55/57uzshv8/11/

```js
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
        var colours = new Array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3');
        var shapes = new Array('option 9', 'option 2', 'option 3');
        var names = new Array('option 4', 'option 6', 'option 7');
        var names1 = new Array('option 8', 'option 3', 'option 3');
    
        switch (ddl1.value) {
            case 'Colours':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, colours[i], colours[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'Shapes':
                ddl2.options.length = 0; 
            for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, shapes[i], shapes[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'Names':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, names[i], names[i]);
                }
                break;
               case 'Names1':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, names1[i], names1[i]);
                }
                break;
                default:
                    ddl2.options.length = 0;
                break;
        }

    }

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
    }
```

```css
#dropdowns h3 {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

select {
   color: #333333;
   opacity: .5; 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;  
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */    
   -moz-border-radius: 0;  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */     
   border-radius: 0;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
    min-width: 20vw;
    min-height: 2vw;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#personal {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
}

#dropdowns {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 10%;
}

.i-am-a {
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 41.5px;
    padding-left: 5px!important;
    min-height: 4.02vh!important;
    margin-bottom: -2px!important;
    color: black!important;   
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdowns">
<select id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="Colours">Test 1</option>
<option value="Shapes">Test 2</option>
<option value="Names">Test 3</option>
<option value="Names1">Test 4</option>
</select>
<div id="personal"></div>
<select id="ddl2">
<option value="">Looking to</option>
</select>


<div id="personal-nav-spacing"><a href="#"></a></div>
</div>
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated! This has been driving me mad for ages.

Comment: Is the issue that you don't have a "go" button appearing or...? Sorry if I missed it in your post but I don't particularly see what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying! The issue is I don't know how to get a go button to link to a page which a user choses from from of the dynamic dropdown boxes.

Comment: you would create the button (much the same way you created the options lists) and then attach a `click` event listener to it and just have that page change the `window.location` to the URL you want.

Comment: I've got to go for a bit, but if your question isn't answered by the time I come back I'll go ahead and type it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the wait, please see the code / comments below. I would like to show you a further refactored set of code, but I got back much later than I had anticipated. I will try and get around to it tomorrow as soon as possible.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1, ddl2) {
  var _config = {
    'Colours': ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
    'Shapes': ['option 9', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
    'Names': ['option 4', 'option 6', 'option 7'],
    'Names1': ['option 8', 'option 3', 'option 3']
  }; //You had a lot of repeated instructions in your code;
  //This is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), which you can read about at <http://www.json.org/>

  if (!_config.hasOwnProperty(ddl1.value)) return false;
  //If we don't have a property corresponding to the items in our config, stop execution.

  while (ddl2.childNodes.length > 0) {
    ddl2.removeChild(ddl2.lastChild);
    //If the second list has any children nodes, remove them.
  }

  _config[ddl1.value].forEach(function(item, i) {
    //More info about this function at
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = item;
    option.setAttribute('value', 'http://google.com/');
    ddl2.appendChild(option);
  });

}

function makeGoButton(item) {

  if (item.value == '') return false; //If the value is an empty string, stop execution
  var goButton = document.getElementById('go-button');
  //Get the goButton element

  if (!goButton) {
    //If the element doesn't exist, make it.
    goButton = document.createElement('button');
    goButton.innerHTML = "Go!";
    goButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    item.parentNode.appendChild(goButton); //add it to the parent of the item argument.
    goButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'goButtonGo()');
  } else {
    //If it does exist, make sure you can see it.
    goButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}

function goButtonGo() {
  window.location = document.getElementById('ddl2').value;
  //change the window location.
}
```

```css
#dropdowns h3 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
select {
  color: #333333;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-width: 20vw;
  min-height: 2vw;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#personal {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
#dropdowns {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
.i-am-a {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 41.5px;
  padding-left: 5px!important;
  min-height: 4.02vh!important;
  margin-bottom: -2px!important;
  color: black!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdowns">
  <select id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="Colours">Test 1</option>
    <option value="Shapes">Test 2</option>
    <option value="Names">Test 3</option>
    <option value="Names1">Test 4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="personal"></div>
  <select id="ddl2" onchange="makeGoButton(this)">
    <option value="">Looking to</option>
  </select>


  <div id="personal-nav-spacing">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

A way to do a unique URL for every combination

```js
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1, ddl2) {
  var _config = {
    'Colours': [{
      'name': 'option 1',
      'url': 'http://yahoo.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 2',
      'url': 'http://google.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 3',
      'url': 'http://gmail.com/'
    }], //End colours array
    'Shapes': [{
      'name': 'option 9',
      'url': 'http://msn.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 2',
      'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 3',
      'url': 'http://facebook.com/'
    }], // End Shapes Array
    'Names': [{
      'name': 'option 4',
      'url': 'http://aol.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 6',
      'url': 'http://css-tricks.com/'
    }, {
      'name': 'option 7',
      'url': 'http://wordpress.com/'
    }], //end Names array
    'Names1': [{
        'name': 'option 8',
        'url': 'http://php.com/'
      }, {
        'name': 'option 3',
        'url': 'http://phpbb.com/'
      }, {
        'name': 'option 3',
        'url': 'http://msdn.com/'
      }] // end Names1 array
  }; //You had a lot of repeated instructions in your code;
  //This is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), which you can read about at <http://www.json.org/>

  if (!_config.hasOwnProperty(ddl1.value)) return false;
  //If we don't have a property corresponding to the items in our config, stop execution.

  while (ddl2.childNodes.length > 0) {
    ddl2.removeChild(ddl2.lastChild);
    //If the second list has any children nodes, remove them.
  }

  _config[ddl1.value].forEach(function(item, i) {
    //More info about this function at
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = item.name;
    //the item variable is now the object from the array of our selection (colours, etc.)
    //How we access the items stored in an array is by using object.keyName, in our case our two keys were 'name' and 'url', so we use item.name and item.url
    option.setAttribute('value', item.url);
    ddl2.appendChild(option);
  });

}

function makeGoButton(item) {

  if (item.value == '') return false; //If the value is an empty string, stop execution
  var goButton = document.getElementById('go-button');
  //Get the goButton element

  if (!goButton) {
    //If the element doesn't exist, make it.
    goButton = document.createElement('button');
    goButton.innerHTML = "Go!";
    goButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    item.parentNode.appendChild(goButton); //add it to the parent of the item argument.
    goButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'goButtonGo()');
    goButton.setAttribute('id', 'go-button');
  } else {
    //If it does exist, make sure you can see it.
    goButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}

function goButtonGo() {
  window.location = document.getElementById('ddl2').value;
  //change the window location.
}
```

```css
#dropdowns h3 {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
select {
  color: #333333;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-width: 20vw;
  min-height: 2vw;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#personal {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
#dropdowns {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
.i-am-a {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 41.5px;
  padding-left: 5px!important;
  min-height: 4.02vh!important;
  margin-bottom: -2px!important;
  color: black!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdowns">
  <select id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="Colours">Test 1</option>
    <option value="Shapes">Test 2</option>
    <option value="Names">Test 3</option>
    <option value="Names1">Test 4</option>
  </select>
  <div id="personal"></div>
  <select id="ddl2" onchange="makeGoButton(this)">
    <option value="">Looking to</option>
  </select>


  <div id="personal-nav-spacing">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for taking the time to write this. How would you suggest allowing each option to have an individual URL based on the selection?

Comment: you would need to have a way of figuring that out. I would suggest altering the structure of the JSON object so that each item in the sub array is actually an object (or array, doesn't particularly matter) containing the URL and the option name you want displayed.

Comment: Thanks for that man! Trying to fiddle with it however I am not getting it redirecting when all implemented. it doesnt seem to want to go to the correct page - https://jsfiddle.net/slinger55/odo07bqt/1/

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: It won't work in a fiddle. Try taking the code and putting into an HTML file on your machine and testing it. It works for me here.

Comment: Thank you very much, got it working perfectly with all the correct content in now as well! One final question if possible, I am trying to set the go button font and weight to 500 and colour to white. I already have the variable button to so set it to button one and tried this:

Comment: goButton.style.fontWeight = "500";
    goButton.style.fontcolor = "white"; However it doesnt seem to want to listen to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Manage to crack it now! Only thing left is to stop the button when appearing pushing content to the left.

Comment: Just make sure you add whatever styles you want to it when it's created and it should be fine. I didn't add any to it.